# How can I use 'in return for' in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> If you've ever swapped one of your toys with a friend **in return for** one of their toys, you have bartered.

I understand the meaning of the sentence but when I try to use the phase in my own writing I have no idea where I should use. I think it is because I do not understand the phrase grammatically.

If I had to write the sentence on my own, I would have written like this.

> If you've ever swapped one of your toys with your friends' toy, you have bartered

To me, it seems that the sentence that I wrote basically has the same meaning as the one with the phase "in return". But I want to write sentences with phrases in like "in return for". The problem is that I do not know how to use the phrase "in return for" by myself when writing an essay.

Can we say the phrase is used as a verb in the sentence? or is there specifically given a grammatical name to this type of phrase?

Answer (score 1):

' **In return for**' is not a verb. It is a prepositional phrase. You can use it as you use other prepositions.

**In return for** means as an exchange for something.

1. My brother bought me a pen **in return for** my help.
2. I will do anything **in return for** her love.